# Silly question about group rings

Tags: ring-theory, group-rings

Let $R$ be a ring and $G$ be a finite group, and $RG$ be the group ring.

What does it mean to say that $|G|$ is invertible in $R$? Since $|G| \in \mathbb{N}$, $|G|$ is not an element of $R$, does it mean that $|G|$ is invertible is same as there exists an element $x \in R$ s.t. $x|G| = 1$? Does it mean that $|G|$ is invertible in $R$ if there exist an element of $R$ which if added $|G|$ times gives $1$?

But if it means this, what does $\frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{\alpha \in RG} \alpha$ mean? How could $|G|$ divide an element of a ring?

Answer (score 2):

As $R$ is a ring, it contains a multiplicative identity $1_R$. As such, there is a unique ring homomorphism $\phi : \mathbb{Z} \to R$ given by $\varphi(n) = n\cdot 1_R$; note, $n\cdot 1_R$ does not denote the multiplication of two elements of $R$, rather it is shorthand for the sum of $n$ copies of $1_R$ if $n$ is positive, or $|n|$ copies of $-1_R$ (the additive inverse of $1_R$) if $n$ is negative.

The element $n\cdot 1_R$ is sometimes denoted by $n$, but to distinguish it from the element of $\mathbb{Z}$, the notation $\overline{n}$ is also used; the source you are using follows the former convention. Therefore, the statement "$|G|$ is invertible in $R$" really means $|G|\cdot 1_R$ is invertible in $R$. That is, $|G|\cdot 1_R$ has a multiplicative inverse, which is an element $x \in R$ such that $x(|G|\cdot 1_R) = (|G|\cdot 1_R)x = 1_R$. Note that

$$1_R = (|G|\cdot 1_R)x = (\underbrace{1_R + 1_R + \dots + 1_R}_{|G|\ \text{summands}})x = \underbrace{1_Rx + 1_Rx + \dots + 1_Rx}_{|G|\ \text{summands}} = |G|\cdot x$$

so as you correctly said in your post, the invertibility of $|G|$ implies that there is an element (namely $x$) which, when added to itself $|G|$ times, becomes $1_R$.

In the formula you wrote, $\frac{1}{|G|}$ is used to denote the multiplicative inverse of $|G|\cdot 1_R$ (namely $x$); the motivation for this notation is the identity $|G|\cdot x = 1_R$. So the formula could be rewritten as $x\sum_{\alpha\in RG}\alpha$ which is well-defined if $RG$ is finite.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: For your last question, 1/|G| denotes the x.

Comment: there seems to be at least five questions op is posing? what does this yes mean?

Comment: I count three, the yes answers the first two and the general spirit; the comment above, the third one

Comment: this site will not be of much use if you see lots of one word answers. it will help if you can elaborate some of the reasons for your answer.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez What do you mean by saying that $1/|G|$ denotes the x

Comment: simply asking what is $\frac {r}{|G|}$ where $r \in R$?

Comment: 1/|G| denotes the x such that x|G|=1. r/|G| denotes xr.

Answer (score 0):

For example, if $G=S_3$ and $R=\mathbb{Z}_{19}$ then $|G|=6$ is invertible in $R$ (in fact, $\bar 6$ , the image of $6$ under the canonical morphism $\mathbb{Z}\to R$, is ), since $6 \cdot 16 = 96 = 1 (\!\!\!\mod 19)$ that is, $\bar 6 \cdot \overline{ 16} = \bar 1 $ in $
\mathbb{Z}/19$.

Comment: Yeah but here ring is $\mathbb{Z_{19}}$. What if your ring is $C[0,1]$